# In Next.js 13 app directory, how do I incrementally generate new pages?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have multiple items from a CMS. `/items/1` all the way to `/items/9999`. The content is immutable, so I don't have to worry about `revalidate`ing them.

However, items do get added to the CMS frequently, maybe multiple times in a day. I want to make a static website. How can I add new static pages incrementally?

The CMS isn't handled by me, so there's no way I can add a hook.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration

Comment: @BradyDean that's not the app directory.

Comment: @BurgerBurglar in the top left, click on the drop down and select "Using App Router."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/segment-config#dynamicparams), by default, route segment parameters that were not statically generated at build-time by `generateStaticParams` function will be generated on demand. These non-generated segments will use [Streaming Server Rendering](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/streaming-and-suspense#streaming-server-rendering). This is basically the equivalent to `fallback: true` on `getStaticPaths` function on `pages` folder page components.

Just make sure to perform the appropriate checks on your page component in case the requested data doesn't exist in the CMS. That way you can throw a Not Found error and render a 404 UI making use of the [not-found.js](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/not-found) file. Example from the [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/notfound#notfound):

```
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

export default async function Profile({ params }) {
  const user = await fetchUser(params.id);

  if (!user) {
    notFound();
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So the new pages aregenerated on request. Is there any way to generate it ahead of time?

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, the answer is no. You can't generate a dynamic static page ahead of time if the resources needed to build it are not available in the data source (the CMS).

Comment: I guess I should word it better: the data is available at the CMS via a new path `/items/99999`, but this is not part of the `getStaticPaths` at initial build. Is there a way to add additional paths before the first view?

Comment: I guess you could use [On Demand Revalidation](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/revalidating#on-demand-revalidation), but otherwise, you'd need to do a re-build.